# Achieve the xml hierarchy structure having an ordered list with level numbers

Tags: java, xml

I have a list of numbers which represents the levels in a xml tree.
For example I have the folowwing list:

```
 0, 1, 2, 2, 1
```

and the xml (with 'lev' elements) needs to be:

```
<lev>
  <lev>     
    <lev>
    </lev> 
    <lev>
    </lev>  
  </lev>
  <lev>
  </lev>
</lev>
```

How can I form this xml having just that list? 
I need a **recursive** method, actually I need this for a xsl file, but It will be great also having just as a Java code - with parsing that list.

I'm not sure if this is possible, having just that list.
Any help will be great!
Thanks.

**Later edit:**

For the above list let's say that we introduce the position too:

```
Level     Position
   0        0
   1        1
   2        2
   2        3
   1        4
```

If we are having in the list a number(level) x and after it we are having a number(level) y where y<=x we know at that point that the last element(s) (x, x-1, ..., y) needs to be closed when creating the xml.

Ex.:

- when we are at position 3 (level 2) we know that the Element at position 2 (also with level 2) needs to be closed
- when we are at position 4 (level 1) we know that the Element at position-s 3 (level 2) and 1 (level 1) needs to be closed

Comment: Homework? If not, please describe a bit more what context this is used in. Will the numbers always start from zero, rise monotonically to a maximum and then back to 1? Can there be a jump (say from 2 to 5)?

Comment: Is not homework.I wanted initially to present an example of what I did but I think will be more confusing... The first number in the list is always 0 and yes, we can have 2 and than 5.

Comment: Please answer my questions (and probably provide more examples) - your question isn't fully specified currently.

Comment: OK. Hopefully someone will provide an answer - I need to do some work for a bit. It seems like in your extended question you've mostly answered it yourself, though...

Comment: see that nobody wants ... if you have time please give some ideas ..

Comment: @Chouchenos: yes lol :-) But do you have any solutions ?:D

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is overkill for this. Also, there's no need for a "position" value. Here's a pseudocode solution

Assume a function `next()` that returns the next input value, or zero for EOF.

```
curLevel = 0
n        = next();
do 
{
  while(curLevel <= n)
  {
    open tag
    ++curLevel
  }
  n = next();
  while(curLevel > n)
  {
    --curLevel
    close tag
  }
}
while(curLevel > 0)
```

Note that the corner case of an empty input file will produce one open/close pair.  Check for EOF a different way and modify the code to handle it if that's not desired.